# How to get Rendering from RenderingReference

Tags: presentation, mvc

We are using Sitecore 9.1 `MVC`.

It is possible to get all rendering references for a given item by using:

```
item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true)
```

However, this will give me an array of RenderingReference.

The module I am developing, needs to run this pipeline:

```
PipelineService.Get().RunPipeline<RenderRenderingArgs>("mvc.renderRendering", new RenderRenderingArgs(rendering, writer));
```

Which requires a `Rendering` object and not a 'RenderingRef' object.

How do I get the corresponding `Rendering` from  RenderingRef?

Comment: Please check this thread https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/how-to-render-an-mvc-rendering-in-code

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Abhishek Malaviya, there was an answer at this reference:

https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/sitecore-item-rendering-best-practice/

For completeness sake, this is the code that creates a Rendering from a RenderingRef:

```
var renderings = new List<Rendering>();

var refs = Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Context.Device, false);
if (!refs.Any())
  return null;

var renderingReferences = refs.Where(r => !(Context.Database.GetItem(r.RenderingID).TemplateID.ToString() == "{86776923-ECA5-4310-8DC0-AE65FE88D078}" && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Settings.DataSource))).ToList();

if (!renderingReferences.Any())
  return null;

renderings.AddRange(renderingReferences.Select(r => new Rendering
{
    RenderingItemPath = r.RenderingID.ToString(),
    Parameters = new RenderingParameters(r.Settings.Parameters),
    DataSource = r.Settings.DataSource
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get corresponding renderings of item using below code :

```
 string deviceName = "Default".ToLower();
            var deviceItem = item.Database.Resources.Devices.GetAll().Where(d => d.Name.ToLower() == deviceName).First();
            if (deviceItem != null)
            {
                var renderings = item.Visualization.GetRenderings(deviceItem, false);
                if (renderings != null)
                {
                     foreach (var renderingref in renderings)
                    {

                    }                   
                }

            }
```

Comment: That will give me an array of RenderingRef. What I would like is the Rendering object, not the RenderingRefs :)